# software to keep a list of IP that try to access ssh over a set of rules and feasibility

Tags: network, linux, brute-force, ssh, port-knocking

i'm interested in software or set of scripts to keep a lists of filtered IP that attempt to brute-force ssh, and to label an IP as brute-forcing i would add some checks like:

- one attempt to log as root is a ban
- three attempts to log as a nonexistent user in a day is a ban
- a port scan is a ban (this i know there are tools for this like [psad](http://cipherdyne.org/psad/))

i'm wondering if there is a tool that allows this, also, you think its feasible to keep such an ever growing lists or there are better approaches for this?

Given the levels of brute-force ssh traffic i get, i'm tempted to filter everything by default and whitelist specific client ips (i don't host web so it is an option) but i would like to hear other approaches for this matter

thanks!

Comment: For what operating system?

Comment: ubuntu linux 10.10

Answer (score 8):

[Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/) has different defaults, but I think you could probably configure it meet your desires. I personally think the 10 bad logins per IP default is more than sufficient to keep resources down and avoid locking yourself out by typo or brainfart.

Comment: +1 fail2ban is what I use. To confirm, it does allow you to customise your rules including ban length, number of failures and any IP addresses that should be ignored/have different rules.

Comment: I agree. Definitely prefer more than 3 fails to instigate a ban. 10 is better. a brute force would typically have hundreds so you aren't losing security for this slight gain in user-friendliness.

Comment: It includes functions for whitelisting IPs, adjusting ban length, and selecting the number of failures among lots of other goodies. I don't think it includes the ability to set a different number of attempts based on differing criteria, though.

Comment: What I'm seeing is anywhere between 8-20 on the aggregate once to twice daily with some outliers once or twice a week in the dozens. (80-90 or so)

Answer (score 4):

Look into using [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/).

You can build custom rules based on OSSEC's default ruleset.  For example, OSSEC by default alerts on the following SSH events:
http://www.ossec.net/doc/rules/rules/50_sshd_rules.xml.html

An example of a custom rule:

```
<rule id=“100005” level=“10” frequency=“3” timeframe=“600”>
<if_matched_sid>100124</if_matched_sid>
<description>3 Failed passwords within 10 minutes</description>
</rule>
```

You can create customized active responses (e.g. call a script to add iptables rules or to add the source IP to a flat file or database):
http://www.ossec.net/doc/manual/ar/ar-custom.html

Answer (score 4):

[DenyHosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/) is ssh attack mitigation software that uses a shared database to identify and prevent ssh attacks. It has good configurable settings and is written in Python, so it is moderatly portable. Plus, it has a beautiful [statistics page](http://stats.denyhosts.net/stats.html).

Answer (score 4):

Or configure the sshd

- to permit keypair-based login
- not to permit password-based login
- not to permit root login